# Get key pressed from DOM input event (or equivalent solution)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

## Background:

I am writing a script that does some stuff when a user clears an `input type="search"` (essentially the same as type=text) using backspace or delete. I want to address the case where user highlights original text and starts typing new text, and also pasting.

Because of this I cannot use `keydown` (fires before input value is changed). Cannot use `keypress` (need to fire when backspace/delete is pressed, and it fires too early as well). Using `keyup` is bad because I can't clear when `value === 1` (might already be several characters in the field). I can build in some slop but then it won't clear right away which looks buggy.

## Question:

So the [DOM input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) fires right when the value is updated, which is exactly what I want (tested using jQuery on 'input'). However, I cannot find the captured key (which I need to differentiate between deleting and entering content). I couldn't find great info on the spec. It seems like this is going to be implemented in the `data` section of the event, which does not yet have any browser support. **Does that mean it is currently impossible to get the key from the `oninput` event? If so, how do most developers handle this?** I imagine wanting the key immediately after it is entered is very common, surely there is a decent solution for this?

#### Current implementation for the curious:

For the time being I am grabbing the value right after `keydown` by using a `setTimeout` of 0. This gets me both the key and the updated value, but feels dirty and requires extra handlers for `onpaste` and such. While writing this it occurs to me I could probably use `oninput` by keeping track of the last value and comparing to current to differentiate between entering and deleting, but that doesn't seem all that much better, and would still require a separate paste handler since I want my event to fire every time a user pastes, and it doesn't seem to have any flags that would let me know the event was a paste.

Comment: you can set a prop onkeydown and look at that prop oninput. something like `elm.onkeydown=function(e){elm.kc=e.keyCode;};` dupe for paste too, in case it wasn't a right-click paste

Comment: Ah that's a clever workaround too. Supply the event I want with the info it needs. Still requires two handlers and adds DOM manipulation though.

Comment: hmm. well you could set a document-level onkeydown event, and say `myGlobalKC=e.keyCode` to avoid the DOM part. in that case, `myGlobalKC` would be ~like BASIC's INKEY: the last key pressed.

Comment: Yeah, not as heavy but setting globals feels dirty too.

Comment: it doesn't have to be a "global", it just has to be somewhere the interested code can see; that can be a private var defined just outside the two handlers, or `myLib.kc`, or anything else really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided the last suggestion of dandavis was the best workaround. I used keydown to grab key info and triggered the action on paste, empty field, or 1 character and last character was not backspace/delete (on `input` does not fire on enter, modifier keys, etc. so those don't need to be accounted for).

The code looks like this:

```
var onClear = function(action){
  var lastKey;
  jQueryObject.keydown(function(e){
    lastKey = e.which;
  });
  jQueryObject.on('input', function(){
      if( !this.value.length || (this.value.length === 1 && lastKey !== 46 && lastKey !== 8) ){
        action();
      }
  });
  jQueryObject.on('paste', function(){
    action();
  });
}
```